# Making benzoyl chloride - yellow liquid and a precipitate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am attempting to produce benzoyl chloride from benzoic acid (I need to convert an isotopically labeled version, so I can't just buy the acyl chloride). I am reacting benzoic acid with excess oxalyl chloride in DCM, and the reaction looks like its proceeding quantitatively, but when I try to rotovap off everything except the product my solution turns pale yellow and I get a white solid.

Both the yellow liquid and white solid appear identical on TLC, and the NMR is consistent with benzoyl chloride, but the physical appearance doesn't seem to match.

Can anyone suggest what might be going on?

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question, but supposed that you're planning to synthesize an ester or amide: Did you consider to activate the labelled benzoic acid *in situ* using tBOC or DCC?

Comment: Have you prepared benzoic anhydride?

Comment: Water is pretty ubiquitous. I wonder if TLC is the way to test for benzoyl chloride. Wouldn't benzoyl chloride readily hydrolyze back to benzoic acid?